# Separating modules in NodeJS for use with a single object

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a NodeJS + ExpressJS + Socket.IO server and I am trying to divide my different namespaces into different modules.

Essentially I want to require the socket.io library in server.js, but have access to the `io` variable from my modules like this:

**server.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var _log = require('./logging/loggly.js').Client();

// Global NS
var SK = {
    Namespaces:{}
};

var Migrations = require('./sockets/migrations');
var Backups = require('./sockets/backups');
var Cloudmanager = require('./sockets/cloudmanager');


SK.Namespaces[Migrations.NS] = Migrations;
SK.Namespaces[Backups.NS] = Backups;
SK.Namespaces[Cloudmanager.NS] = Cloudmanager;

....
....
```

**migrations.js**

```
var exports = module.exports = {};


///////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Migrations Namespace
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////
exports.NS = 'migrations';

exports.socket = io.of('/'+exports.NS); // PROBLEM IS 'io' IS UNDEFINED HERE

exports.socket.on('connection', function(socket){

});
```

I have basically the same code in all 3 of my socket.io namespaces, but I don't have access to the `io` variable that is used in `server.js`.  Is there a way to have access here? Do I just use a require()? Whats the best way to achieve this functionality?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export a function from `migrations.js` that accepts the `io` value as a parameter:

```
module.exports = function (io) {
  var socket = io.of('/'+exports.NS);
  socket.on('connection', function(socket){});
  return {
    NS: 'migrations',
    socket: socket,
  };
};
```

Then simply require and invoke this function in your `server.js`:

```
var Migrations = require('./sockets/migrations')(io);
```

Comment: Ahhhh. Makes total sense. thanks a lot! I'll accept your answer soon :)